# Term to describe keyword followed by statement block

Tags: terminology, language-agnostic, language-specifications

Is there a general term to describe a keyword followed by a statement block?  E.G.

```
if() {statement block}
while() {statement block}
try{statement block}
finally{statement block}
```

Or even something made up:  `controlScope{statement block}`

Comment: Well, I define this as [Control Structures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow#Control_structures_in_practice)

Comment: "What is the name of this thing" questions are off-topic. These are poor questions for the same reasons that "identify this obscure TV show, film or book by its characters or story" are bad questions: you can't Google them, they aren't practical in any way, they don't help anyone else, and allowing them opens the door for the asking of other types of marginal questions. See Also [Let's Play the Guessing Game](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game)

Answer (score 3):

I'd call them "Block Identifiers". In languages that support it, they are typically [lexical closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29) which makes them more or less equivalent to functions. Thus they are "named functions" rather than anonymous functions which would be something like "BlockVariable = {block}".